# The last date of modification of your local copy in CVS

Tags: git, version-control, cvs

I made some changes in my local copy without commit. Now I want to find the last date of modification of local copy. Can you please help me which command should be used.

Comment: is this a git or a cvs question?

Answer (score 0):

Any answer is highly dependent on the working environment (not identified in the question).  CVS itself does not offer this functionality per se, though it can support a solution that leverages the status of a checkout.

If one assumes use of a GNU/Linux, or similar shell environment, one might create a script that examines only the files that CVS recognizes as locally modified, uncommitted, or not added.  The following solution is environment dependent and rather awkward, but does illustrate the concept.

A sample shell session might look like this:

```
$ cvs -nq update 2>/dev/null \
> | awk '/^[M?]/ { system(sprintf("stat \"%s\"", $2)) }' - \
> | grep ^Modify: \
> | sort \
> | tail -1
Modify: 2016-04-27 10:22:35.000000000 -0500
```

This command sequence is run at the top of the checkout so the results include all sub-directories within it.

The `cvs -nq update 2</dev/null` command generates a relatively terse report of file status.  It only reports locally modified or uncommitted new files, unknown files, and files that have been updated upstream.

The `2>/dev/null` suppresses uninteresting `stderr` output of the `cvs` command.

The `awk` statement uses a regular expression to match only the locally added and locally modified files in the work space.  It then extracts the relative path to the file and performs a `stat` operation to get modification time of each file.

The `grep` statement discards uninteresting output of the `stat` command.

A `sort` command orders the output modification times from oldest to newest, and `tail -1` shows only the most recent modification time.

The most recent CVS-recognized "change" to the checkout is in the result and follows the word "Modify:".